# ListPlot3D, how not to connect some points?

Tags: plotting

I have a list `{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, ... , {xN, yN, zN}}`, which I am plotting using `ListPlot3D`. The {x, y} values are in three of the four quadrants, that is $x$ and $y$ cannot both be positive. In the plot, I want this region to just remain white. However, because there are data points in the quadrants to the left {x<0, y>0} and below {x>0, y<0} this quadrant {x>0, y>0}, Mathematica connects the two quadrants and eventually gives regions within this absent quadrant.

Mathematica seems to be interpolating across a region where I have no data points. How do I ensure that nothing is plotted in the quadrant where there are no data points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) to limit the region for plotting. For instance, for a start you could use `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x < 0 || y < 0]` to limit plotting to the region where x OR y are negative.

Here is some made up data for demonstration:

```
coords =
  Select[
   Tuples[Range[-3, 3, 0.05], 2],
   Not[Positive[#1] && Positive[#2]] & @@ # &
 ];

list = {#1, #2, Sin[#1^2 - #2^2]} & @@@ coords;
```

The results with just `ListPlot3D` displays the "interpolation" you mentioned:

```
ListPlot3D[list, ViewPoint -> {0.2, -0.5, 3}]
```

[image: there is data in the positive, positive quadrant]

Instead, with RegionFunction, there is no data there:

```
ListPlot3D[
  list, 
  ViewPoint -> {0.2, -0.5, 3}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x < 0 || y < 0]
]
```

[image: no data in the positive, positive quadrant]